# Choropleth, the color and the data

Tags: vba, excel

I am attempting a dashboard/Choropleth. I have downloaded Europe from [here.](http://www.clearlyandsimply.com/clearly_and_simply/2009/06/choropleth-maps-with-excel.html)

I will keep it simple the first thing I would like to do is to change the grey and black color. To blue. Can anyone help?? The code that came with the template is below

```
Option Explicit

Function udf_RGB(myR As Byte, myG As Byte, myB As Byte) As Long

  udf_RGB = RGB(myR, myG, myB)

End Function

Sub CheckColor(myCell As Range, myNameToShape As String, myValueToColor As String)
Dim myShape As Shape
Dim myTargetCell As Range
Dim myColorCode As Long

On Error GoTo Catch
  Set myTargetCell = Range(myNameToShape).Columns(1).Find(myCell.Name.Name, LookAt:=xlWhole)
  Set myShape = Sheets(1).Shapes(myTargetCell.Offset(0, 1))
  GoTo Finally

Catch:
  Exit Sub
Finally:

  On Error GoTo 0

  If myCell.Value < Range(myValueToColor).Cells(2, 1).Value Then
    myColorCode = Range(myValueToColor).Cells(1, 2).Value
  Else
    myColorCode = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(myCell.Value, Range(myValueToColor), 2, True)
  End If

  myShape.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = myColorCode

End Sub

Sub UpdateMap()
Dim myCell As Range

  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

  For Each myCell In Range("MapNameToShape").Columns(1).Cells
     CheckColor Range(myCell.Value), "MapNameToShape", "MapValueToColor"
  Next myCell

  Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would help if you could format the code as code (use the {}). Besides, wouldn't it be easier if you do such a thing with Gimp or Photoshop?

Comment: Hi. Thank you a person from Stack has corrected the format for me. I will be sure to not make this mistake again :-) Thank you for the responses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kind of a cheap way to do it but if you change this line

```
udf_RGB = RGB(myR, myG, myB)
```

to

```
udf_RGB = RGB(myR, myG, 255)
```

it will shade with blue instead of black.